How to change .esd files to .cab files for Win 10 interface language change?
I want to change the interface language for my PC that has Windows 10 Single Language version.
According to a thread here I need to download the language package from uupdump.net and change the .esd to .cab files
I have used the script from this github which created a temp folder with hundreds of folders inside but i have not been able to find any .cab file, am I missing something??
